# Script not picking up composed names, only picking non composed ones

Tags: lua

```lua
onTextMessage(function(mode, text)
  if config.serverEnabled and config.enabled then
    if mode == 20 then
      if string.find(text, "invited you to") then
        local regex = "[a-zA-Z]*"
        local regexData = regexMatch(text, regex)
        if regexData[1][1]:lower() == config.serverLeader:lower() then
          local leader = getCreatureByName(regexData[1][1])
          if leader then
            g_game.partyJoin(leader:getId())
            g_game.requestChannels()
            g_game.joinChannel(1)
            shouldCloseWindow = true
```

So I have this code for a MMORPG I play. It basically automatically accepts a party invite by picking up the name of the party leader from a text log, as it gets invited the message is sent to this text log with the name of the party leader who is inviting them.
Problem is it is not picking up composed names, so it only works when the party leader has one name... how to fix that?
I already tried adding a space, a _and a space at the end of the Z, a space between zA in local regex = "[a-zA-Z]*" and it didn't work.

Comment: Give an example of `text` parameter value having problem.

Comment: Ok so if I understood you correctly, let's say the player gets invited to the party by a character named  Theophrastus Bombastus, so it will display the message on server log "Theophrastus Bombastus has invited you to his party." The script will only pick up the first name "Theophrastus" and since the player isn't called just that it wont accept the party invite because it wont find it.

Comment: `local name = text:match"^(.-) has invited you to" or ""; if name:lower() == config.serverLeader:lower() then`

Comment: It worked perfectly just like that :O! Thank you very much!!